# R generate a sequence like 111222333444555666777.....505050

Tags: r, repeat, sequences, seq

I want to generate a sequence just like :

```
c(rep(1,7),rep(2,7),rep(3,7),rep(4,7),rep(5,7),rep(6,7),rep(7,7))
```

But for large number instead of 7, say 100.

How can I do it without repeating until 100?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `each=` argument to `rep`:

```
rep(1:7, each=7)
```

Comment: Ahh... how could I forget `each`. :D

Answer (score 1):

A generalization of your request:

> rep(1:m, each=n)

In your example, `m=7` and `n=100`.